# S3 Bucket Policy not accepting .io domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was trying to make an alias for my bucket but I can't make the setting correct as S3 bucket policy doesn't accept my policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "qweewfewr",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mydomain.io/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Error msg

```
Add a new policy or edit an existing bucket policy in the text area below. Learn more.
Policy has invalid resource - arn:aws:s3:::mcommerce.io/*
```

Comment: I don't understand your use of the phrase *make an alias for my bucket* in the context of bucket policies.  Please clarify what an "alias" means, to you.  Is the value you're using at the end of the policy the exact name of your bucket?

Comment: for example the end point is `https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mybucketname/img.jpeg` I want it to be `assets.mydomain.com/img.jpeg`.

Comment: If you want to access a bucket using the hostname `assets.example.com` then your bucket's actual name has to be `assets.example.com` and a DNS record can then be created with an alias in Route 53... but that is not directly related to the bucket policy, and that's why your question is still unclear.  Are you using your actual bucket name in the `Resource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message seems pretty clear to me. The resource name you are using does not exist. You need to replace `mydomain.io` with the name of your bucket you are trying to open access to.

As far as how to make an alias for the bucket, that has absolutely nothing to do with the bucket policy. That bucket policy is to tell S3 that it has permission to serve the items in it to whoever asks for them. Making an alias is a different process altogether.

To make an alias, you need to open the Route53 console and add a new `A Record` that is the domain address you are trying to use. Then you can add your bucket address `https://<region>.amazonaws.com/<bucketname>/` and viola, you have an alias web address tied to the bucket. For a full tutorial [check out this article.](http://pixelcog.com/blog/2013/routing-with-s3/)

Comment: I create a new bucket with my subdomain, I didn't use Route53, and it worked just like that. Now I'm confused what route53 is for..

Comment: Route53 is the DNS name server for amazon. If you have another name server already set up with your URL (which it sounds like you do) then you don't need it.